# Bash Code Block Syntax colouring

Tags: linux, bash, shell, markdown, visual-studio-code

For markdown in vscode, in a triple backtick code block what is the name I should use for bash?
I have tried:

- bash
- sh
- shell

(example:

```bash

if [ "$BLEG" != xxx ]; then
      command
fi

```

All to no avail.

Is there a list anywhere the shows the codes that vscode allows for?

thanks!
-Eric

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `shellscript`:

````
```shellscript

if [ "$BLEG" != xxx ]; then command; fi

```
````

Found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/d2a151fcc69bc3307fa3b75d167841177cbb9f41/extensions/shellscript/package.json

Comment: I just added "bash", "sh" and "zsh" to the list, this will come through in the March or April release https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/commit/10927a864df60789a1ef7be382db856e867b58ab